# Drupal boolean radio button/check boxes select the N/A option

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, radio-button, migration

I'm working on a migrate class that needs to select the N/A option from the boolean check boxes/radio buttons. I have configured my fields so `1 == True` and `0 == No`. But I would like to select the `N/A` option whenever nothing is specified in the source.

The function I call in the `prepareRow` function looks like this:

```
protected function utcYesNoBoolean($value) {
  $upper = strtoupper($value);

  switch ($upper){
    case "YES":
      return 1;
      break;

    case "NO":
      return 0;
      break;

    //Not filled in so set to NA
    default:
      return NULL;
      break;
  }
}
```

So if the source looks like this:

[image: source example]

- id 1: result => 1 => select Yes
- id 2: result => 0 => select No
- id 3: result => NULL? => select N/A

Should I just do it like this and return a `NULL` and ignore the fact that the field is not selected in the UI, or is there a way to select the `N/A` option? What value should I be returning in order to select the `N/A` option? I tried with returning `-1`, `NULL` and `"N/A"` but no success.

Or is there maybe an option to set the default value of the field to `N/A`using the migrate field mapping?

[image: radio buttons]

Note: This on Drupal 7 using Commerce Kickstart if that matters. Please also note it is required to set the with PHP code in the migrate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I figured it out myself. When you update the field on a product from `No` to `N/A`. Save it and edit it again you will see that there is nothing selected anymore.

So in the database this will also result in an empty/deleted field/record. So there is no need to set it to anything else as `Yes` or `No`. The `N/A` button is there to remove the value in case you don't want the value to be there anymore.

Thanks everyone who read the question, I could have figured this out earlier if checked the Drupal database earlier. I hope this answer is useful for some one else in the future.